# SQL migration fails because of syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql, migration

I want to run the following two migrations on a postgres DB. The second migration fails but it's tricky to debug.

```sql
CREATE TABLE decks 
(
    id uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid () PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    updated_at timestamp without time zone,
    display_name text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE levels 
(
    id uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid () PRIMARY KEY,
    deck_id uuid NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_deck_id FOREIGN KEY deck_id REFERENCES decks (id)
);
```

Questions:

- Is there a better debug tool than: https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/?
- What is my syntax error?

EDIT: the error message is:

> (details: pq: syntax error at or near ")")

=> Not very helpful I'd say.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: "*Is there a better debug tool than*"  - yes: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Just added the error message.

Answer (score 2):

Incorrect:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_deck_id FOREIGN KEY deck_id REFERENCES decks (id)
```

Correct:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_deck_id FOREIGN KEY (deck_id) REFERENCES decks (id)
```

The list of column(s) of the foreign key need to go in parentheses.

Comment: Thank you! That might be one error but there seems to be another one since it's still failing.

Comment: @siva: works just fine with that change: https://dbfiddle.uk/T4ZpZ9LK

Comment: You are correct. My second mistake was that my formatter added a comma after the constraint. If I remove the comma then it works. Thank you everybody!